# How can I make a Sum Query on Mysql and Two Tables

Tags: mysql, sum, stock

I need help with one query, I don't know how can I make it.
i have one Table (TblParts) With Fields:

### Code Stock StockReplace

```
 1    10    0
 2     5    0
 3    15    0
 11    0    0
 22    0    0
 33    0    0
```

and another Table (TblSust) With Fields

### Code  Replace

```
 1      11
 11      1
 2      22
 22      2
```

This table Shows the replace code of each code, for example, if I don't have stock of code 1, I can use the stock of code 11, and reverse too.

I need a query to add in each TblParts.stockreplace(only where TblParts.stock = 0), the sum of TblParts.stock where TblSust.code = TblParts.code

Example, The result of TblParts Will be:

### Code Stock StockReplace

```
1      10     0
2      5      0
3      15     0
11     0     10
22     0     5
33     0     0
```

But if I have two replace between each, must sum each, and put on TblParts.replacestock the sum.

Some Help to make this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join `tblparts` to a query that calculates the sum:

```
update tblparts p
inner join (
  select s.code, sum(p.stock) total
  from tblsust s 
  inner join tblparts p on s.replace = p.code
  group by s.code
) t on t.code = p.code  
set p.stockreplace = t.total
where p.stockreplace = 0;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tFmgzHSwVYfL3sXjCYcKfs/1).
Results:

```
| Code | Stock | StockReplace |
| ---- | ----- | ------------ |
| 1    | 10    | 0            |
| 2    | 5     | 0            |
| 3    | 15    | 0            |
| 11   | 0     | 10           |
| 22   | 0     | 5            |
| 33   | 0     | 0            |
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables and use a correlated sub query to get the replace NB I have altered your sample data

```
drop table if exists tblparts,tblsust;
create table tblparts
(Code int, Stock int, StockReplace int);
insert into tblparts values
( 1  ,   0  ,  0),
( 2  ,   5  ,  0),
( 3  ,  15  ,  0),
( 11 ,  10  ,  0),
( 22 ,   0  ,  0),
( 33 ,   0  ,  0);

create Table TblSust
(Code int, `Replace` int);
insert into tblsust values
( 1   ,   11),
( 11  ,    1),
( 2   ,   22),
( 22  ,    2);

select p.code,p.stock,
        coalesce(
        (select p1.stock from tblparts p1 where p1.code = s.`replace`) 
        ,0) r
from tblparts p
left join tblsust s on s.code = p.code
order by p.code
;

+------+-------+------+
| code | stock | r    |
+------+-------+------+
|    1 |     0 |   10 |
|    2 |     5 |    0 |
|    3 |    15 |    0 |
|   11 |    10 |    0 |
|   22 |     0 |    5 |
|   33 |     0 |    0 |
+------+-------+------+
6 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

replace is a reserved word so is backticked here.

If there are multiple replacements sum the stock values and then join

```
create table tblparts
(Code int, Stock int, StockReplace int);
insert into tblparts values
( 1  ,   0  ,  0),
( 2  ,   5  ,  0),
( 3  ,  15  ,  0),
( 11 ,  10  ,  0),
( 15 ,   2  ,  0),
( 22 ,   0  ,  0),
( 33 ,   0  ,  0);

create Table TblSust
(Code int, `Replace` int);
insert into tblsust values
( 1   ,   11),
( 11  ,    1),
( 2   ,   22),
( 22  ,    2),
(  1  ,   15);

select p.code,p.stock,
        coalesce(
        s.stockreplace
        ,0) r
from tblparts p
left join 
(select s.code, sum(stock) stockreplace
from tblsust s
join tblparts p  on s.`replace`= p.code
group by s.code
order by p.code
) s on p.code = s.code
;

+------+-------+------+
| code | stock | r    |

+------+-------+------+
|    1 |     0 |   12 |
|    2 |     5 |    0 |
|    3 |    15 |    0 |
|   11 |    10 |    0 |
|   15 |     2 |    0 |
|   22 |     0 |    5 |
|   33 |     0 |    0 |
+------+-------+------+
7 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks For Response P.Salmon, The problem is that it's not adding. Try add ( 33 , 0 , 0); to tblparts and ( 1 , 15); to tblsust

The result for code = 1 must be r=12 (10 + 2)

But i get separately values:

1 0 10
1 0 2

Comment: Edited for multiple replacements.

Comment: P.Salmon, you are great, now its working like i want. Last question, how can i insert r Result on p.StockReplace?